# ClaimsTransformation seems to create an extra attribute

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using a claim transformation, which results in creating an extra attribute in my B2C database with the datatype (odata.type) of the value of the new attribute. What am I doing wrong? Why am i getting the extra attribute?

Here is what I see in B2C Graph for the user:
                "extension_0428f3354957491e96bb7ce51b81d46a_TOUAcceptedDateTime@odata.type": "Edm.DateTime",
            "extension_0428f3354957491e96bb7ce51b81d46a_TOUAcceptedDateTime": "2019-01-18T21:43:36.3993383Z"

This is how the transformation is used in the profile which writes the new attribute out (it is not used anywhere else):

```
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetConsentDateTime" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
```

Defined as:

```
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetConsentDateTime" TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime">
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TOUAcceptedDateTime" TransformationClaimType="currentDateTime" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.

For a `DateTime` attribute, Azure AD B2C reads and writes:

1. The attribute value as the string representation of the date-time value.
2. An "metadata" value that specifies the attribute type.

The "metadata" value helps with serialization of the attribute value.